# Transit through Schengen area with Bulgarian visa?

Tags: schengen, transit, bulgaria, ukrainian-citizens

I am Ukrainian and in early stages of planning trip to conference in Bulgaria later this year.

Strangely there seems to be no direct flights from Kiev to Sofia. From quick search the most affordable routes seem to go through Schengen area (Paris, Vienna, etc), both directions.

Is Bulgarian visa sufficient to make such a trip or would I need anything extra to transit through airport in Schengen area?

Does it count as "international" airport area, since Bulgaria is part of European Union, however not of Schengen area?

Comment: I gathered that much.  Diplomatic/Official/Biometric?

Comment: @Karlson The regular "international passport" kind, the biometric ones are still not getting issued I think (from next year or something, unless it gets postponed again).

Comment: Generally as a Ukrainian citizen, you don't need a transit visa for airside transit at an airport in the Schengen area. Depending on the airport, the facilities may however not allow you to remain in the transit area when changing planes, e.g. if you arrive to and depart from different terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=UA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=BG&EM=UA&TR=AT&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) you don't need a visa to transit through (picked Austria as a transit point).

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets in transit. *Note: TWOV is not possible when arriving from a non-Schengen Member State AND departing to a Schengen Member

Comment: You write one thing (no visa required) and quote something else ("... except for Holders of onward tickets in transit"). As I wrote in the comment to the question, depending on the airport, it is not at all self-evident, that he can stay in the airside transit area between flights.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't see the conflict: *Visa Required, except for Holders of onward tickets in transit*.  If you want to pick a different transit point on Timatic you're welcome to try.  Same applies to connection through Germany except for a limited number of airports. https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=UA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=BG&EM=UA&TR=DE&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#

Comment: I think part of the issue is definition of "in transit", especially how it applies to specific situation with Bulgaria as EU, but non-Schengen.

Comment: @Rarst when you're flying from non Schengen to non Schengen country you will stay in the transit area meaning you don't need a visa. It makes no difference that Bulgaria is in EU.

Comment: @Dirty-flow: The problem is exactly, that you may not be able to stay in the transit area even if you come from and fly to a non-schengen country. Not all airports offer such facilities and it may even depend on the airline and/or if you have to change terminals.

Comment: @Karlson: As Rarst says, the issue is indeed the definition of "transit", or more exaclty if the airport has facilities allowing you to stay in transit between the flights. I alredy wrote that in my first comment. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo You have specific examples of the airline hubs that don't have such a facility?  To my knowledge Vienna does, so does Frankfurt.

Comment: @Karlson: In Germany, airside transit is only possible in Frankfurt, Munich, Hamburg, Cologne, Düsseldorf and Berlin-Tegel. I don't know the other airports very well, but at least in Munich, I doubt that transit between the terminals is possible without going through immigration. There are 34 further airports in Germany with schedules flights offering *no* airside transit, e.g. Berlin-Schönefeld, Frankfurt/Hahn, Memmingen and Leipzig/Halle to mention some of the larger airports mainly served by budgets airlines.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo To the best of my knowledge there is no flights from Kiev to any of the other 34 airports in Germany. http://kbp.aero/en/passengers/schedule/

Comment: So in a nutshell current state of answer tells me what I need to do (stay in "transit" area), but I will also need to figure out _how_ to do it (ensure that it's definite possibility in specific airport of choice). How would I do that reliably? Try to ensure that terminal matches?

Comment: @Rarst That would be one.  A lot of airports where this may not be possible provide shuttles that stay airside.  You can check the airport maps for details.  Of course you can always switch the to go through Turkey and not worry about a visa at all.

Comment: @Karlson: If it really matters, there are flights from several of these German airports to Zhuliany, one of the other airports in Kiev.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo And home many of those have direct flights to Sofia?

Comment: @Karlson: Dortmund and Stuttgart, but I slowly have absolutely no clue about why you're asking instead of checking yourself if you find this somehow relevant to the question. Are you just trying to find an excuse for the irrelevance of the mistakes in your answer?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo All I am trying to suggest is that while the situation you describe is possible in order to get into the situation requiring a visa you will need to do multiple stops within Schengen, or construct separate itineraries that put in into an airport without an international transit area, which while possibly cheaper is more inconvenient.  And cost of obtaining a visa will likely offset any savings achieved for this particular trip.

Comment: I think we all agree that it's possible to come up with route that will require entering Schengen zone and visa for it, no need to keep arguing that. :) The takeaway is that it's practical to transit through large airport with international area so that entering Schengen and visa are not required. I think @Tor-EinarJarnbjo is arguing that answer in current form only applies to such specific situation, not _general_ travel through Schengen with Bulgarian visa.

Comment: Due to pilot strike ended up transiting through Moscow on the way to Bulgaria (no issues/questions), but as planned through Paris CDG on the way back (no issues, leaving Bulgaria was asked to explain on passport control if Paris is my final destination — showed printout of my connecting Paris–Kiev flight check in).